# How to use explicit wait object in different methods from the same class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In a selenium java program, I created an explicit wait condition inside the class. But unable to call this wait object in different methods from the same class.

Below is the code I have written:

```
public class AutomationScenarioWithCustomWaits {

        public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SDET_Certification_2020\\SDETCertification2020\\chromedriver.exe");
        login();
        clickPIMforActions();

    public static void login() throws IOException {

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");

        System.out.println("OrangeHRM is launched successfully...");
        System.out.println("");

         // Specify the path of file
          File src=new File("C:\\SDET_Certification_2020\\SDETCertification2020\\DataSet.xlsx");
         // load file**strong text**
         FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
        // Load workb`enter code here`ook
        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);         
        // Load sheet- Here we are loading first sheetonly
        XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("txtUsername"))).sendKeys(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
        System.out.println("User name is entered successfully...");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("txtPassword"))).sendKeys(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStri`enter code here`ngCellValue());
        System.out.println("Password is entered successfully...");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("btnLogin"))).click();
        System.out.println("Login Button is clicked..");
        System.out.println("User is in: " + driver.getTitle() + " page");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void clickPIMforActions() {
//      WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        pim = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu_pim_viewPimModule\"]/b")));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(pim).click().build();
        System.out.println("PIM menu is clicked...");

    }

}
```

When I try to execute, it is giving the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:782)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at seleniumAssignment_3.AutomationScenarioWithCustomWaits.<clinit>(AutomationScenarioWithCustomWaits.java:33)
```

Please suggest me how to used single explicit wait object in all the methods from same class.

Comment: is 'driver' initialized?   Does WebDriverWait depend on 'webdriver.chrome.driver' (which you initialize *after* trying to create the WebDriverWait)?

Comment: `public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);` it's static which means, it's initialized at the beginning of the program. Your driver is `null` at the time

Comment: Thanks to both David and Fenio... i initialized wait before driver initialization and this is causing the issue.

This is what i did to resolve:
1. Crated wait variable before driver initialization.
2. Then initialized the wait after driver initialization. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did to solve the issue:

1. Created wait before initialization of driver.

*static WebDriverWait wait;*

2. Created driver and initialized it.

*WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();*

*wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);*

3. Then used wait in my entire code including all methods from the same class.